# Understanding forest options when customising trees

Tags: trees, forest

This is a follow-up to [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172442/39222) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172434/39222).

The solution offered there includes the following code at the start of the `forest` environment:

```
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-13pt) -|   
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
```

How does this code achieve the desired layout? I am unclear how the explanation of the relevant option on page 33 of the manual relates to the resulting diagram. In general, I find `forest`'s documentation rather difficult to follow when it comes to customising tree layout (as opposed to specifying the relationships between nodes etc.) but I would like to understand it since `forest` seems to be more powerful and flexible in principle than the available alternatives.

For completeness, the full code of Gonzalo Medina's solution is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
where n children=0{font=\sffamily}{},
for tree={
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-13pt) -|   
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  l sep=10pt,
} 
[\mbox{}
  [$C1_2$
    [$C1$ [a]]
    [$C2$ [b]]
    [$C3$ [c]]
    [$C4$ [d]]
  ]
  [$C2_2$
    [$C5$ [e]]
    [$C6$ [f]]
    [$C7$ [g]]
    [$C8$ [h]]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the following variation to the example helps to understand the specification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
where n children=0{font=\sffamily}{},
for tree={
  draw=cyan,
  line width=0.2pt,
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-13pt) -|   
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  l sep=10pt,
} 
[root
  [$C1_2$
    [$C1$ [a]]
    [$C2$ [b]]
    [$C3$ [c]]
    [$C4$ [d]]
  ]
  [$C2_2$
    [$C5$ [e]]
    [$C6$ [f]]
    [$C7$ [g]]
    [$C8$ [h]]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In

```
\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
  (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-13pt) -|   
  (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
```

`!u` refers to the current node; so

```
!u.parent anchor
```

starts a path on the declared parent anchor for the current node; then

```
-- +(0,-13pt)
```

causes the path to move downwards `13pt` and

```
-| (.child anchor)
```

makes the path go horizontally and then vertically until it reaches the specified anchor for the child nodes. `\forestoption` simply access the values for the option used in its argument.

Comment: Thank you! The second half of this is the bit I was really struggling with. This is really extremely helpful.