# Mendelian Inheritence Chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, graphs, tikz-qtree

I would like to be able to create a simple chart that depicts Mendelian Inheritence, like this one:

[image: Inheritence]
<sub>(source: [palomar.edu](http://anthro.palomar.edu/mendel/images/genotypes_of_pea_plants.gif))</sub>

I'm not too picky about how it looks, as long as it depicts it accurately.

Comment: Can you show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) containing what you've tried so far and tell us what specific issues you are having?

Comment: *I'm not too picky about how it looks, as long as it depicts it accurately.* Oh but we are. Once you ask the question we own it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Impossible to see a tree and not to give an option using the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\def\GG{\textcolor{DarkGreen}{G}}
\def\YY{\textcolor{Gold}{Y}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-15pt) -|   
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
}
[,shape=coordinate,name=root
  [\YY\GG]
  [\YY\GG
    [\YY\YY
      [\YY\YY,name=level3] [\YY\YY] [\YY\YY] [\YY\YY]
    ]
    [\YY\GG
      [\YY\YY] [\YY\GG] [\YY\GG] [\GG\GG]
    ]
    [\YY\GG
      [\YY\YY] [\YY\GG] [\YY\GG] [\GG\GG]
    ]
    [\GG\GG,name=level2
      [\GG\GG] [\GG\GG] [\GG\GG] [\GG\GG]
    ]
  ]
  [\YY\GG]
  [\YY\GG,name=level1]
]
\draw (root) -- ++(-15pt,0) node[anchor=east] {\YY\YY};
\draw (root) -- ++(15pt,0) node[anchor=west] {\GG\GG};
\foreach \Nodo/\Nombre in 
  {root/{parent generation},level1/{f1 generation},level2/{f2 generation}}
  \node[anchor=west] at ([xshift=15pt]level2|-\Nodo) {\Nombre};
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (level3|-0,0)
  {\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\,=\,}l@{}}
    \YY & yellow allele \\
    \GG & green allele
    \end{tabular}%
  };
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Explnatory comments

In a comment it has been requested to suppress all not essential information (labels and colors) and show some of the steps of the tree formation.

We start with a tree having empty root and four children and make some step by step changes

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}% just an empty root with four children using the default settings
[
  [YG]
  [YG]
  [YG]
  [YG]
]
\end{forest}\qquad
\begin{forest}% we declare the root as a ''coordinate'', so it takes no space
[,shape=coordinate
  [YG]
  [YG]
  [YG]
  [YG]
]
\end{forest}\qquad
\begin{forest}% we change the shape for the edges to a ''fork'' shape and name the root for later use
for tree={
edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-15pt) -|   
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
}
[,shape=coordinate,name=root
  [YG]
  [YG]
  [YG]
  [YG]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now we add some more children and the two nodes to the side of the root

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-15pt) -|   
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
}
[,shape=coordinate,name=root %  root with empty content; the shape is coordinate so it takes no space; we just give it a name for later use
  [YG]
  [YG]
  [YG]
  [YG]
]
 % we use the name for the root here
\draw (root) -- ++(-15pt,0) node[anchor=east] {YY};
\draw (root) -- ++(15pt,0) node[anchor=west] {GG};
\end{forest}\qquad
\begin{forest}
for tree={
edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-15pt) -|   
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
}
[,shape=coordinate,name=root %  root with empty content; the shape is coordinate so it takes no space; we just give it a name for later use
  [YG]
  [YG [YY] [YG] [YG] [GG] ]
  [YG]
  [YG]
]
 % we use the name for the root here
\draw (root) -- ++(-15pt,0) node[anchor=east] {YY};
\draw (root) -- ++(15pt,0) node[anchor=west] {GG};
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This part

```
edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-15pt) -|   
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
```

just prescribes how the shape for the path connecting a node and its children will look like (the default is just a straight line, but here we need a "fork" shape); in [`this answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172527/3954) to [Understanding forest options when customising trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172498/3954) I explained the syntax used in a similar case.

Comment: This is also a really neat solution, thank you!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the syntax here for `forest`. Do you think it would be possible for you to edit you answer to remove the legend, sidetext and colors, and to limit the tree to just the 2 parents and the next immediate generation?

Comment: @user2515526 Sure. What part of the syntax are you having trouble with?

Comment: @user2515526 I added some initial steps in the tree construction and some other explanatory comments.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{M}
\setcounter{M}{0}

\newcommand{\Mend}[5][]{%
    \begin{scope}[#1]
    \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0)
        node[pos=0,below=5pt] (\theM1) {#2}
        node[pos=.333,below=5pt] (\theM2) {#3}
        node[pos=.5,coordinate] (\theM3) {}
        node[pos=.666,below=5pt] (\theM4) {#4}
        node[pos=1,below=5pt] (\theM5) {#5} ;
    \foreach \i in {0,...,3} {\draw (-1.5+\i,0)--(-1.5+\i,-5pt); }  
    \end{scope}
    \stepcounter{M}
    }

\newcommand{\Y}{{\color{orange}\bf\textsf{Y}}}
\newcommand{\G}{{\color{green}\bf\textsf{G}}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-.75cm]

\draw (-.5,0) node[left] {\Y} -- (.5,0) node[right] {\G} ;
\node[right] at (3,0) {parent generation};

\Mend[shift={(0,1)}]{\Y\G}{\Y\G}{\Y\G}{\Y\G}
\draw (0,0)--(03) ;
\node[right] at (3,1.5) {$f_1$ generation};


\Mend[shift={($(02)+(0,1)$)}]{\Y\Y}{\Y\G}{\Y\G}{\G\G}
\draw (02)--(13) ;
\node[right] at (3,3) {$f_2$ generation};

\begin{scope}[shift={($(13)+(0,.5)$)}]
\Mend[shift={(-6,1)}]{\Y\Y}{\Y\Y}{\Y\Y}{\Y\Y}
    \draw (11.south)--(23) ;
\Mend[shift={(-2,1)}]{\Y\G}{\Y\G}{\Y\G}{\Y\G}
    \draw (12.south)--(33) ;
\Mend[shift={( 2,1)}]{\Y\G}{\Y\G}{\Y\G}{\Y\G}
    \draw (14.south)--(43) ;
\Mend[shift={( 6,1)}]{\G\G}{\G\G}{\G\G}{\G\G}
    \draw (15.south)--(53) ;

\end{scope}

\node[right] at (-7,1) {\Y\ = yellow allele};
\node[right] at (-7,2) {\G\ = green allele};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use of `tikz` tree

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}%[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,positioning,arrows,mindmap,matrix}
\newcommand{\Y}{\color{yellow!50!red}Y}
\newcommand{\G}{\color{green!50!blue}G}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    community_label_style/.style= {font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries,minimum size=0.7cm,text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex,},
    edge from parent fork down,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance = 2cm, level distance =2cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=4.5cm},
    level 4/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick,]
\node{}
child[] {node[community_label_style] (p)  {$\Y\Y\G\G$} 
     child[]{node[community_label_style] (f1) {$\Y\G$}}  %1
     child[]{node[community_label_style] ( ) {$\Y\G$}    %1
            child[]{node[community_label_style] (v1) {$\Y\Y$}
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (a) {$\Y\Y$}}
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (b) {$\Y\Y$}}
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (c) {$\Y\Y$}}
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (d) {$\Y\Y$}}
            }
            child[]{node[community_label_style] (v2) {$\Y\G$}
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (a) {$\Y\Y$}}
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (b) {$\Y\G$}}
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (c) {$\Y\G$}}           
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (f2){$\G\G$}}
            }
            child[]{node[community_label_style] (v3) {$\Y\G$}
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (a) {$\Y\Y$}}          
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (b) {$\Y\G$}}
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (c) {$\Y\G$}}        
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (d) {$\G\G$}}
            }
            child[]{node[community_label_style] (f2) {$\G\G$}
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (a) {$\Y\Y$}}         
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (f1){$\Y\G$}}
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (c) {$\Y\G$}}         
                    child[]{node[community_label_style] (d) {$\G\G$}}
}}
     child[]{node[community_label_style] (v5) {$\Y\G$}}  %1
     child[]{node[community_label_style] (f1) {$\Y\G$}}  %1
     };
\node[right=1cm of p](){parent generation};
\node[left=2.5cm of p](y){{\Y}=yellow allele };
\node[below=0.5cm of y](){{\G}=green allele};
\node[right=1cm of f1](){f1  generation};
\node[right=1cm of f2](){f2  generation};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `EDIT`: Do you know if there's a way to remove the top line above the parent YYGG?

Comment: Yes, you need to modify the tikzset. For your convenience, copy and paste this to replace the old one with care.    `level 1/.style={sibling distance = 2cm, level distance =2cm,
      edge from parent/.style={draw=none}},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm,edge from parent/.style={draw}},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=4.5cm,edge from parent/.style={draw}},
    level 4/.style={sibling distance=1cm,edge from parent/.style={draw}},`

Answer (score 3):

This is shamelessly appropriated from [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175689/). It adapts that code to use an experimental `justtrees` package which makes it easy to align the level descriptions on the right. It also shows how to add the legend etc. as part of the tree using `forest`'s `afterthought`. This saves naming nodes unnecessarily.

The other aspect of the `justtree` environment which is helpful here is that you do not need to specify a phantom or empty root node as with the `forest` environment itself.

```
\documentclass[svgnames,border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{justtrees}% version 0.03

% original forest tree is from Gonzalo Medina's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175689/

\def\GG{\textcolor{DarkGreen}{G}}
\def\YY{\textcolor{Gold}{Y}}

\begin{document}

\begin{justtree}
  {
    for tree={
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      font=\sffamily,
    },
    just format/.style={font=\sffamily},
  }
  [\YY,
    afterthought={
      \node  [anchor=north, align=left, font=\sffamily] at (.north -| here)
      {\begin{tabular}{r@{ = }l}
          \YY & yellow allele\\
          \GG & green allele
        \end{tabular}
      };
    }
  ]
  [, right just=parent generation, afterthought={\draw (.south) -- (.south |- !p.east) (!p.east) -- (!n.west);}
    [\YY\GG, right just=f1 generation]
    [\YY\GG
      [\YY\YY, right just=f2 generation, name=here
        [\YY\YY]
        [\YY\YY]
        [\YY\YY]
        [\YY\YY]
      ]
      [\YY\GG
        [\YY\YY]
        [\YY\GG]
        [\YY\GG]
        [\GG\GG]
      ]
      [\YY\GG
        [\YY\YY]
        [\YY\GG]
        [\YY\GG]
        [\GG\GG]
      ]
      [\GG\GG
        [\GG\GG]
        [\GG\GG]
        [\GG\GG]
        [\GG\GG]
      ]
    ]
    [\YY\GG]
    [\YY\GG]
  ]
  [\GG]
\end{justtree}

\end{document}
```

[image: just an inheritance chart...]