# I want Tikz template for taxonomy Tree like the below mentioned image.

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-trees, tikz-styles

[image]

I could not find any Tikz template to fit in the same amount data like the below image. I did not get the same kind of template also. Am trying to find if there is any other alternative or same kind of template.

Comment: `forest` is good at compact trees. Since you don't provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) there's nothing to play with, but ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make things tighter by reducing the level and sibling distances, using a smaller font etc. etc. but `forest` does a good job of packing stuff in. The `edge path` is adapted from [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176649/).

[image: compact tree]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      grow=east,
      parent anchor=south east,
      child anchor=south west,
      align=center,
      l sep+=10pt,
      % path is based on Gonzalo Medina's answer
      % ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176591/typesetting-genealogical-trees/176649#176649
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, rounded corners=5pt, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) [out=0, in=180] to (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label} -- (.south east);
      },
      for root={
        ellipse,
        draw,
        parent anchor=east,
      },
    }
    [some root\\node
      [child\\node
        [grandchild\\node
          [great-grandchild\\node
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
        ]
        [grandchild\\node
          [great-grandchild\\node
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [, calign with current
      [child\\node
        [grandchild\\node
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
        ]
        [grandchild\\node
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
        ]
      ]
      ]
      [child\\node
        [grandchild\\node
          [great-grandchild\\node
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
        ]
        [grandchild\\node
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Tightening things up:

[image: tighter tree]

```
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      grow=east,
      parent anchor=south east,
      child anchor=south west,
      anchor=south,
      align=center,
      l sep+=2.5pt,
      s sep+=-5pt,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
      % path is based on Gonzalo Medina's answer
      % ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176591/typesetting-genealogical-trees/176649#176649
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, rounded corners=5pt, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) [out=0, in=180] to (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label} -- (.south east);
      },
      for root={
        ellipse,
        draw,
        parent anchor=east,
      },
    }
    [some root\\node
      [child\\node
        [grandchild\\node
          [great-grandchild\\node
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
        ]
        [grandchild\\node
          [great-grandchild\\node
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [, calign with current edge
      [child\\node
        [grandchild\\node
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
        ]
        [grandchild\\node
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
        ]
      ]
      ]
      [child\\node
        [grandchild\\node
          [great-grandchild\\node
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
        ]
        [grandchild\\node
          [great-grandchild\\node
          ]
          [great-grandchild\\node
            [great-great grandchild node]
            [great-great grandchild node]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! this is what  have been looking for!Than you so much!