# Forest tree genealogy

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, genealogy

How to obtain PDF that reflects the order of argument put into brackets as shown in the code?

```
My father 
My father's father 
My father's mother
My mother   
My mother's father 
My mother's mother
```

If you see the PDF diagram, it is the inverse. I took this code from
[Typesetting genealogical trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176591/typesetting-genealogical-trees)

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,backgrounds,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{forest}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=east,
    grow=east,
    draw,
    anchor=west,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (.child anchor) -| +(-5pt,0) -- +(-5pt,0) |-
        (!u.parent anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  }
[Me
    [My Father
      [My Father's Father
      ]
      [My Father's Mother
      ]
    ]
    [My Mother
      [My Mother's Father
      ]
      [My Mother's Mother
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you out to solve your issue?

Comment: It is a good practice on this site to accept an answer to thank the work that other made to solve your problem, or even to comment anything regarding the answer. Please take into account that nobody here is receiving any pay off for the work and research to meet your initial concern.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Even though this will work fine for this simple tree, note that you are probably better off using the newer genealogytree package for drawing genealogical trees.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{genealogypicture}[
  timeflow=left,
  level size=5cm,
  node size=1cm,
  box={halign=center, valign=center},
  ]
  parent{
    g{Me}
    parent{
      g{My Father}
      p{My Father's Father}
      p{My Father's Mother}
    }
    parent{
      g{My Mother}
      p{My Mother's Father}
      p{My Mother's Mother}
    }
  }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) For Sportmanship, for going the extra mile and for educating us all.

Comment: I'm not sure about the 'probably better off'. I've tried using `genealogytree` and it is rather obscure, to say the least, if you are not familiar with the technical terminology used to describe genealogies. And there are also a lot of things which you can't do but which seem obvious things to want to do. At least, I couldn't figure out how to do them. If you are a professional or expert amateur genealogist, it is almost certainly the best option, as you say. But I suspect I'm not the only one who will find it practically impossible to navigate the documentation. (And I really, really tried.)

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. They were very useful to me.

Answer (score 3):

In order to revert the order of the *children* in the tree as shown in the arguments, you will need to add the character `'` right after the word `grow` in the tree options, like this: `grow'=east`.

It will show the expected order from top to bottom. So with the same code

```
[Me
    [My Father
      [My Father's Father
      ]
      [My Father's Mother
      ]
    ]
    [My Mother
      [My Mother's Father
      ]
      [My Mother's Mother
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

we obtain the following outputs:

### With *grow=east*

[image]

### With *grow'=east*

[image]

Comment: It would be better to include a complete MWE in your post. Questions aren't the only posts which benefit from such things.