# Extend three-tier tree to four tier using forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, trees

I would like to extend the three tier in the [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434585/rotate-text-in-tikz) to a four-tier tree. To something as shown in the figure below. This is the MWE provided here.
The question appears quite simple, but I have tried almost all I could before posting this question

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
draw,
grow'=0,
},
forked edges,
where n children=0{}{rotate=90},
[Root
[Branch A
[Branch A1
]
[Branch A2
]
]
[Branch B
[Branch B1
]
[Branch B2
]
]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        grow'=east,
        draw,
        anchor=west,
    forked edges,
    where n children=2{rotate=90, anchor=center}{}, % <---
    }
    [Root
        [Branch A
            [Branch A1
                [Sub-branch a1]
            ]
            [Branch A2
                [Sub-branch a2]
            ]
        ]
        [Branch B
            [Branch B1
                [Sub-branch b1]
            ]
            [Branch B2
                [Sub-branch b2]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

in code is (in comparison to yours) `where n children=0{}{rotate=90}` replaced with `where n children=2{rotate=90, anchor=center}{},`

Comment: Yes! You are absolutely Right!

Answer (score 3):

The reason my original answer rotates all but the last nodes is because it uses the

```
where n children=0{}{}
```

conditional to decide whether to rotate or not. Basically, if a node has children, it gets rotated; if it has no children (is a leaf), it doesn't.

There are several ways to alter this for you tree. One is to rotate nodes with 2 or more children, as [Zarko suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434746/).

Another is to rotate nodes in the first two levels (levels `0` and `1`).

```
where level<=1{}{}
```

A third is to create a style which you can apply to just those nodes you want rotated.

```
, <style name> % add to each node you want to apply <style name> to
```

In my example, `rot` is defined to do the rotation, so

```
, rot
```

is added to each of the three to-be-rotated nodes. This is the simplest solution if you want to be able to extend the tree and have fine-grained control over what gets rotated.

Here is code illustrating each of these two alternative approaches:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\forestset{
  rot/.style={rotate=90},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    grow'=0,
  },
  forked edges,
  where level<=1{rot}{},
  [Root
  [Branch A
    [Branch A1 [Sub-branch A11]
    ]
    [Branch A2 [Sub-branch A21]
    ]
  ]
  [Branch B
    [Branch B1 [Sub-branch B11]
    ]
    [Branch B2 [Sub-branch B21]
    ]
  ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    grow'=0,
  },
  forked edges,
  [Root, rot
  [Branch A, rot
    [Branch A1 [Sub-branch A11]
    ]
    [Branch A2 [Sub-branch A21]
    ]
  ]
  [Branch B, rot
    [Branch B1 [Sub-branch B11]
    ]
    [Branch B2 [Sub-branch B21]
    ]
  ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same in each case:

[image: identical trees]

Comment: nice explanation (which is missing in my answer) +1!

Comment: @Zarko Your answer does the job perfectly well. (At least, it got my vote.) I just thought this might be useful lest we get a new question if the OP need to add another node :-). Give an OP a fish vs. teach an OP to fish ... ?

Comment: @cfr the OP keeps learning to fish infact he has an edit giving more details on one of the answers i.e extending heterogeneous number of sub-branches which was meant to undergo review . However, the OP really appreciate your answers and explanation

Comment: @Abdulhameed ;) Forest takes getting used to. At least, so I found. I only 'got' it by pestering somebody here for help/explanations.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Hoping I will get more used to it. I had to create a new question as it took me much time trying to extend it but couldn't get through!

Comment: @Abdulhameed There is the manual, but there's also a beginners' introduction on CTAN now for Forest (not part of the package). I've not used the latter, but it is supposed to be quite good.