# How do I rotate labels in a tree diagram drawn with forest?

Tags: diagrams, labels, rotating, forest

I am in the process of drawing a huge tree diagram that I want to fit on a single page (at the moment it does not fit on an A1 page). A simple way to do this would be to rotate the labels. I know this question has already been answered here: [Rotate text in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434585/rotate-text-in-tikz), but I still can't figure out how to do it!

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a1paper, margin=1mm]{geometry}






\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{forest}  
[Omissive Bridging Principles
                         [Attitudinal
                                     [Beliefs
                                             [Wide
                                                  [Ought
                                                        [Positive]
                                                        [Negative]]
                                                  [Reason to
                                                             [Positive]
                                                             [Negative]]
                                                  [Permitted to
                                                               [Positive]
                                                               [Negative]]]
                                             [Narrow
                                                    [Ought
                                                          [Positive]
                                                          [Negative]]
                                                    [Reason to
                                                              [Positive]
                                                              [Negative]]
                                                    [Permitted to
                                                                 [Positive]
                                                                 [Negative]]]
                                             [Doubly Embedded
                                                             [Ought
                                                                   [Positive]
                                                                   [Negative]]
                                                             [Reason to
                                                                   [Positive]
                                                                   [Negative]]
                                                             [Permitted to
                                                                   [Positive]
                                                                   [Negative]]]]
                                     [Credences
                                               [Wide
                                                    [Ought
                                                          [Positive]
                                                          [Negative]]
                                                    [Reason to
                                                              [Positive]
                                                              [Negative]]
                                                    [Permitted to
                                                                 [Positive]
                                                                 [Negative]]]
                                               [Narrow
                                                      [Ought
                                                            [Positive]
                                                            [Negative]]
                                                      [Reason to
                                                                [Positive]
                                                                [Negative]]
                                                      [Permitted to
                                                                   [Positive]
                                                                   [Negative]]]
                                               [Doubly Embedded
                                                               [Ought
                                                                     [Positive]
                                                                     [Negative]]
                                                               [Reason to
                                                                         [Positive]
                                                                         [Negative]]
                                                               [Permitted to
                                                                            [Positive]
                                                                            [Negative]]]]]
                         [Attitudinal
                         [Beliefs
                         [Wide
                         [Ought
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Reason to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Permitted to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]]
                         [Narrow
                         [Ought
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Reason to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Permitted to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]]
                         [Doubly Embedded
                         [Ought
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Reason to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Permitted to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]]]
                         [Credences
                         [Wide
                         [Ought
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Reason to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Permitted to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]]
                         [Narrow
                         [Ought
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Reason to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Permitted to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]]
                         [Doubly Embedded
                         [Ought
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Reason to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Permitted to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]]]]]                                                       
\end{forest}
\end{landscape}








\end{document}
```

Sorry about the second half of the code, it's identical to the first half but badly laid out. I want to rotate pretty much all the labels so they are horizontal (at the moment they are vertical because the page is landscape).

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `for tree={rotate=-90}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a1paper, margin=1mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{forest}  
for tree={rotate=-90}
[Omissive Bridging Principles
                         [Attitudinal
                                     [Beliefs
                                             [Wide
                                                  [Ought
                                                        [Positive]
                                                        [Negative]]
                                                  [Reason to
                                                             [Positive]
                                                             [Negative]]
                                                  [Permitted to
                                                               [Positive]
                                                               [Negative]]]
                                             [Narrow
                                                    [Ought
                                                          [Positive]
                                                          [Negative]]
                                                    [Reason to
                                                              [Positive]
                                                              [Negative]]
                                                    [Permitted to
                                                                 [Positive]
                                                                 [Negative]]]
                                             [Doubly Embedded
                                                             [Ought
                                                                   [Positive]
                                                                   [Negative]]
                                                             [Reason to
                                                                   [Positive]
                                                                   [Negative]]
                                                             [Permitted to
                                                                   [Positive]
                                                                   [Negative]]]]
                                     [Credences
                                               [Wide
                                                    [Ought
                                                          [Positive]
                                                          [Negative]]
                                                    [Reason to
                                                              [Positive]
                                                              [Negative]]
                                                    [Permitted to
                                                                 [Positive]
                                                                 [Negative]]]
                                               [Narrow
                                                      [Ought
                                                            [Positive]
                                                            [Negative]]
                                                      [Reason to
                                                                [Positive]
                                                                [Negative]]
                                                      [Permitted to
                                                                   [Positive]
                                                                   [Negative]]]
                                               [Doubly Embedded
                                                               [Ought
                                                                     [Positive]
                                                                     [Negative]]
                                                               [Reason to
                                                                         [Positive]
                                                                         [Negative]]
                                                               [Permitted to
                                                                            [Positive]
                                                                            [Negative]]]]]
                         [Attitudinal
                         [Beliefs
                         [Wide
                         [Ought
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Reason to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Permitted to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]]
                         [Narrow
                         [Ought
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Reason to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Permitted to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]]
                         [Doubly Embedded
                         [Ought
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Reason to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Permitted to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]]]
                         [Credences
                         [Wide
                         [Ought
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Reason to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Permitted to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]]
                         [Narrow
                         [Ought
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Reason to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Permitted to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]]
                         [Doubly Embedded
                         [Ought
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Reason to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]
                         [Permitted to
                         [Positive]
                         [Negative]]]]]]                                                       
\end{forest}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

You could also change the grow direction and not use landscape.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's really helpful! How do I change the grow direction?

Comment: @JamesSkinner Use `for tree={grow=0}` instead of `for tree={rotate=-90}`. Of course, then you need to drop `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{landscape}`.

Comment: Thanks for helping out a total amateur!!